# Linking different C source file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

I am using visual Studio 2010 for compiling a bunch of source File. I am new to it and I wonder how the object files are linked during compilation. Like in Linux we have make file and rules. Does this suppport makefile? If not how can I compile and set flag during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [makefiles and other command-line tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx) to build using Visual C++ but more typically you handle this by using the GUI to set properties at the Project and File level - start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4457htyc.aspx) for info on this.

The Project/File properties adjust the command-line options passed to the compiler and linker for each compilation unit.  You can view the actual command line that's used in the GUI too.